# SDL_UpdateTexture is slow

Tags: sdl2

I am raytracing on the CPU and I need to display my renders to the screen in realtime. I chose SDL 2 as it seems to be made for low level stuff.

I made this basic test which fills the screen from left to right, one column of pixel per frame. It works as expected, but runs very slowly (~10 fps):

```
int resolutionX = 1920, resolutionY = 1080;

if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, resolutionX, resolutionY, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
PixelBuffer *framebuffer = createPixelBuffer(resolutionX, resolutionY);
SDL_Texture *framebufferTexture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, framebuffer->width, framebuffer->height);

for (int x = 0; x < resolutionX; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < resolutionY; y++)
        setPixel(framebuffer, x, y, 0x123456FF);

    SDL_UpdateTexture(framebufferTexture, NULL, framebuffer->pixels, framebuffer->pitch);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, framebufferTexture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

SDL_DestroyTexture(framebufferTexture);
destroyPixelBuffer(framebuffer);
SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
SDL_Quit();
```

I found `SDL_UpdateTexture` to be the slowdown.

<s>I heard of `SDL_LockTexture` but I don't think I should be using it for write-only operations.</s>
**EDIT :** `SDL_LockTexture` is in fact exactly made for write-only operations.

Am I using this function in a wrong way ? Is there any other way to display my renders in real time ?

Comment: Your actual problem is that you're raytracing on the CPU. Sending data to the graphics card is a slow process in general, and if you do it every frame then you're going to have a bad time. If you want to do real-time raytracing, I would recommend looking into CUDA and OpenCL.

Comment: I already have an OpenCl version of my raytracer, but branching totally ruined the performance. Moreover, I want my scene to be dynamic and maintaining two acceleration structures on both CPU and GPU was too complex. Is there really no way to upload  a simple image every frame ? With todays graphics cards bandwidth I thought it would be trivial task.

Comment: In your sample it appears you are just setting the pixels to a known color to test performance correct? You should get better than 10fps. The code sample is horribly formatted. Are you sure you are writing the whole framebuffer before comitting it? The loop looks funny from my end.

Comment: This code sample simply draws a column of pixels each frame. The framebuffer isn't cleared so I don't need to write every pixels each frame. This piece of code works very well, what do you mean by "horribly formatted"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creating a texture with the pixel format `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888` was the error here. This format might be different from the one used on the GPU, and the texture had to be converted each frame.

I found that using `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888` instead completely solved this issue, and uploading the texture is now instant.

Although the documentation says that `SDL_UpdateTexture` is slow and should be optimized by using `SDL_LockTexture`, I haven't noticed ANY performance boost with it.

Answer (score 7):

> I found SDL_UpdateTexture to be the slowdown.

The SDL [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_UpdateTexture) for `SDL_UpdateTexture` explicitly says in the Remarks section that it is a slow function and only meant for static texture uploads.

> I heard of SDL_LockTexture but I don't think I should be using it for write-only operations.

The [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LockTexture) for `SDL_LockTexture` explicitly says in the Remarks sections that it is intended purely for write operations (which is one of the reasons it's so much faster for this purpose).